# laptop monitor screen having edges around it

Tags: display, monitor

Im new to ubuntu but not that much as im now almost 90% used to it :-). my problem is that my laptop screen was fully utilised in the ubuntu 11.04 natty narwhal but after connecting it to a projector and making it display by setting at the monitor, now it has edges which are pising me off. please advice guys?

Comment: Did you already try to use gnome-control-center, find the monitor settings and then change the display size? gnome-control-center is the last item on the logout/shutdown button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Unity, search for 'Monitors', and if Gnome2, System->Preferences->Monitors, and try to reset the resolution of your display. The highest available resolution is usually the right one.

Comment: yes i did try that but when i set that the right side does nor show anything its just black.

Comment: What do you mean? The right side of the screen is black, or the projector output is black?

Comment: if i put it on a higher resolution the right side of my laptop screen gets black